# Manga where the characters have hexagonal crystals that hold their companions

Tags: story-identification, manga

Manga main character is male .

In the manga I believe characters have hexagon crystals that house their “monsters” which are companions/ they train them. I think they typically interact with them on a small screen/handheld device in which the crystal is plugged in.

I believe he’s invited to some great opening or fair etc where there’s a technology that allows a physical representation of these beings.

It shortly becomes a battle royal / survival game to see who is the strongest . The guy running it has a dragon that wipes out half the creatures in the beginning. When the monster die the crystal breaks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: hexagonal and flat, like a chip, or hexagonal and 3d, somewhat like this crystal? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz#/media/File:Transparency.jpg

Answer (score 2):

This is *[LegendZ](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/legendz)*. It was licensed by Viz, but has expired. It is available to borrow on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/legendz00hira_2).

> What if scientists discovered that mythical creatures like mermaids, dragons and werewolves actually did exist? Better yet, what if any kid could train them to compete in the ultimate role-playing game? Welcome to the world of Legendz, where master trainer Ken Kazaki and his loyal Windragon are about to turn fantasy into reality!

The monsters are the Legendz, which are normally stored in hexagonal crystals, with a computer-like interface device, the talispod.

[image: The crystals and the talispod]

Chapter 6 has the tournament scene; the organizer's son immediately blasts everyone with a dragon, and only 31 participants survive. This also involves the crystals cracking, as mentioned in the question, which normally doesn't occur.

[image: Aftermath of the attack] [image: Crystal cracking]